# Use loop inside aggregate but draw from different groups?

Tags: r, loops, aggregate

I don't know how to think my way out of this one. Here is my data:

```
group <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
gdp <- c(3.5, 4.2, 5, 4, 4.2, 5, 5.5, 6, 3.5, 3.4, 4.0, 4.1, 4.3, 4.7)
year <- c(rep(1970, 9), rep(1971, 5))
df <- data.frame(group, gdp, year) 

  group gdp year
1   1   3.5 1970
2   1   4.2 1970
3   1   5.0 1970
4   2   4.0 1970
5   2   4.2 1970
6   2   5.0 1970
7   2   5.5 1970
8   2   6.0 1970
9   3   3.5 1970
10  1   3.4 1971
11  1   4.0 1971
12  1   4.1 1971
13  2   4.3 1971
14  2   4.7 1971
```

I want to do the following: for each `year`, I want to find the difference in `gdp` between the last variable in a `group` and the first variable in the next `group`.  Ex: what is the difference in `gdp` btwn row 3 and row 4, and btwn row 8 and 9, etc. It obviously needs to be automated as the real data set is large.

I was trying to work with a function within aggregate---aggregate would execute by `year`, while the function would be a `for loop` that scrolled through each `group`, but then my ability to translate what I want to do into code broke down.  How to identify the last variable in a group and do a calculation with the first variable in the next group? I'm not skilled enough with indexing to sort through this.  Advice?

Comment: Check if this helps `library(data.table);  setDT(df)[, list(gdp[1L], gdp[.N]) ,.(group, year)][, V1[-1L]-V2[-.N], year]`

Comment: @akrun Thanks!  Never used data.table so am still sorting what the code means---am about 2/3 there. That is crazy efficient code.

Comment: No problem.  I added the `group` column in the updated post as you mentioned about that in Khashaa's post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr` solution similar to `data.table` solution by @akrun in the comment column

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(year, group) %>% 
    summarise(x1 = gdp[1], x2 = gdp[n()]) %>% 
    mutate(dff = x1 - lag(x2)) %>% 
    na.omit %>% select(-x1, -x2)
#  year group  dff
#1 1970     2 -1.0
#2 1970     3 -2.5
#3 1971     2  0.2
```

Comment: Got identical results from the offerings (`data.table` and `dplyr`). Only chose this because output is slightly easier for me to work with as it includes `group`. Both pkgs new to me, but `dplyr` looks easier to figure out.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We could use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`).  Get the first element (`gdp[1L]`) and last element (`gdp[.N]`) of each grouping variables (`.(group, year)`).  Subtract the new variables ('V1') and ('V2') after removing the 1st and last observation of 'V1' and 'V2' respectively for each 'year'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(gdp[1L], gdp[.N]) ,.(group, year)][,
                         V1[-1L]-V2[-.N], year]
#   year   V1
#1: 1970 -1.0
#2: 1970 -2.5
#3: 1971  0.2
```

If we need the "group" column

```
setDT(df)[, list(gdp[1L], gdp[.N]), , .(group, year)][,
 list(group=group,dff=V1-shift(V2)) , year][complete.cases(dff)]
 #   year group  dff
#1: 1970     2 -1.0
#2: 1970     3 -2.5
#3: 1971     2  0.2
```